# Pyramid CORS does not serve PUT AND DELETE

Tags: python, angular, pyramid

I have a serious problem with pyramid framework.
I add this function to pyramid

```
add_cors_headers_response_callback(event):
    def cors_headers(request, response):
        response.headers.update({
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST,GET,DELETE,PUT,OPTIONS',
        # 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'DELETE, OPTIONS',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
        'Access-Control-Max-Age': '1728000',
        })
    event.request.add_response_callback(cors_headers)

from pyramid.events import NewRequest
config.add_subscriber(add_cors_headers_response_callback, NewRequest)
```

And I can make request to my server using GET, POST methods.
The problem is when I use PUT AND DELETE methods the server sends HTTP status 404, but when I curl the route I get the answer (or using POSTMAN).

I use the same Angular http query with Node.JS and it accepts my request.
I don't know why pyramid refuse to serve the view

```
updatePatternModel(newPattern,url) {
    let fullurl = this.baseUrl + url;
    let data = {
      "rule":newPattern
    }; 
    return this.http.put(fullurl,JSON.stringify(data))
      .map(response => response.json())
      .catch(err => this.handleErrorObservable(err));
  }
```

PYRAMID

```
@view_config(request_method='PUT', route_name='gm')
    def gm(self):
        return dict()
```

EDITED

I make an example

```
from pyramid.view import view_config

@view_config(route_name='gm', renderer='json',request_method="GET")
def get(request):
    return dict(hello="GET")


@view_config(route_name='gm', renderer='json',request_method="POST")
def post(request):
    return dict(hello="POST")


@view_config(route_name='gm', renderer='json',request_method="PUT")
def put(request):
    return dict(hello="PUT")


@view_config(route_name='gm', renderer='json',request_method="DELETE")
def delete(request):
    return dict(hello="DELETE")
```

GET / POST works but PUT, Delete does not !

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from "@angular/http";

import "rxjs/add/operator/map"

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  baseUrl : string = "http://10.0.0.34:8880"
  constructor(public http:Http) { }

  getData(url) {
    console.log('hi');
    let full_url= this.baseUrl + url;
    return this.http.get(full_url)
      .map(response => response.json());
  }
  postData(url) {
    console.log('hello');
    let full_url= this.baseUrl + url;
    return this.http.post(full_url,null)
      .map(response => response.json());
  }
  putData(url) {
    console.log('hello');
    let full_url= this.baseUrl + url;
    return this.http.put(full_url,null)
      .map(response => response.json());
  }
  deleteData(url) {
    console.log('hello');
    let full_url= this.baseUrl + url;
    return this.http.delete(full_url)
      .map(response => response.json());
  }

}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your problem does not seem related to CORS, because the app would not return 404 in that case. The browser would just prevent doing the request. I would look somewhere else if I were you.

Comment: Edited, plz review the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved thanks

```
@view_config (route_name='gm', renderer='json',request_method="OPTIONS")
    def options(context, request):
        request.response.headers.update({
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST,GET,DELETE,PUT,OPTIONS',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
            'Access-Control-Max-Age': '1728000',
        })
        return dict()
```

Comment: Also there is https://gist.github.com/mmerickel/1afaf64154b335b596e4 as a reusable pattern you can include in your app if you prefer.